# Integral of conditional expectation over an event B

Tags: random-variable, conditional-expectation

Could someone help me understand this equality?

Let $\xi$ be a random variable.

$\int_B(\frac{1}{P(B)}\int_B\xi dP)dP=\int_B \xi dP$ for any event $B$.

How do we go from the integral over an event $B$ of the conditional expectation to the unnormalized conditional expectation over such event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just algebra : Note that $\int_B \xi dP$ is a constant. Call it  $A$.
You have that
$$\begin{align}\int_B\left(\frac{1}{P(B)}\int_B\xi dP\right)dP &= \int_B\left(\frac{1}{P(B)}A\right)dP\\
&= \frac{A}{P(B)}\int_B dP\\
&= \frac{A}{P(B)} \times P(B)\\
&= A = \int_B \xi dP\end{align} $$